# cant find overflow menu bar in android studio 2.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I can't find the overflow menu in the android studio 2.0. How can i find it and to add it to my activity? The menu ia the one with three dots. I tried to change the theme of the activity but it didn't worked.
I also tried to change the api of the android from the setting of the android studio but it didn't worked.  please help me here im trying alot but I can't find it.

[here is the menu that im talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmMZo.jpg)

Comment: That has nothing to do with your choice of IDE. That is the overflow of an action bar. It only shows up on Android 4.4+ devices, plus older devices that lack a dedicated hardware MENU option. You don't "add it to [your] activity". You define the contents of the action bar, and the overflow appears if needed (e.g., you have `showAsAction="never"`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get Three dot overflow menu at Android Title Bar, you can follow below steps.

STEP 1 : In layout\activity_main.xml Add below code

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

STEP 2 : At activity\MainActivity.java

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_mainactivity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

STEP 3: Add below code at menu\menu_mainactivity.xml, this code shows RATE, CONTACT, ABOUT Menu items

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="Your Activity Package Name">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_rate_it"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_rate_it"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_contact_us"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_contact"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_about"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_about"
    app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

STEP 4 : At AndroidManifest.xml, Your main activity should have "android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"" i.e. Like

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

STEP 5: at values\styles.xml should have below style in resource tag

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>
```

Above code will add THREE DOTS Menu with Rate, Contact & About menu.